# Grid: repeat(auto-fit,minmax(200px,1fr)) > How to avoid overflowX?

Tags: css, css-grid

Like the question says, Is there any way to avoid the overflow x?

Many Thanks in advance

https://github.com/1GCONF/simple_social_media.git
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7BHB.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
@edit: found the answer:

    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
    <script src="main.js" async defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <section class="section">
        <nav>
            <div class="port_item">Nav</div>
        </nav>
        <div class="port">
            <div class="port_item">Profile</div>
            <div class="port_item">Berichten</div>
            <div class="port_item">Component X</div>
            <div class="port_item">Component X</div>
            <div class="port_item">Component X</div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
<style>
    @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kameron:wght@400;700&display=swap");

    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        outline: 0;
        text-shadow: 0 4px 4px rgba(25, 25, 25, 0.25);
        font-family: 'Kameron', serif;
        font-weight: 200;
    }

    body .section {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 2fr 7fr;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        outline: 2px solid red;
        width: 75%;
        margin: 5ex auto;
    }

    body .section nav {
        outline: 2px solid red;
    }

    body .section .port {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr));
    }

    body .section .port .port_item {
        outline: 2px solid red;
        height: 250px;
    }
</style>
</html>
```

Is responsive and Looks like this:

[responsive grid without queries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4ZN3.png)